# How to change the value of a progress bar through your Main - Nullpointerexception error

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe, progress-bar

I am trying to add a value and display it on a progress bar i have created on a jframe through my main (because i have methods left and right and i want that value to be from 1 of theses) but when i run it it gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

i understand that i have to initialize the "var" so I wont be getting that error but i dont really know how. (i am kind of new to java)

This is my code (there are probably unnecessary stuff here but they were created automatically through the design)

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class UI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form UI
 */
public UI() {
    initComponents();
}


/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    p1hp = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(p1hp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 200, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(768, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(469, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(p1hp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(100, 100, 100))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new UI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
// THIS IS WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO
  p1hp.setStringPainted(true);
  p1hp.setValue(12);
  }

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
public static javax.swing.JProgressBar p1hp;
// End of variables declaration   
}
```

aside that though, i tried creating a button, which i added thoses 2 lines  and it worked fine
(the code for the button isnt here)

**Note1:** I manually maked the progressbar static bacause if not, I would get the error

```
non-static variable p1hp cannot be referenced from a static context
```

**Note2:** I have read this answer:
[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Still not sure how to fix it

**Note3:** I am using Netbeans 8.2

Comment: you want to prevent from the `NullPonterException`?

Comment: yeah, do be more specific, as i said, on a button, it works just fine, i want the same result from my main as i have from a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing Progress bar `p1hp` variable in the `UI` constructor but `UI` constructor is being run inside `invokeLater` that does not guarantee that it will be executed right before the next line that calls `p1hp.setStringPainted(true);`

As a quick fix initialize `p1hp` right in the declaration like this:

```
public static javax.swing.JProgressBar p1hp = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a sample code that starts/stops progress. The code is not intended to be a complete solution but is a good start to get going with Swing and progress handling. I have not commented the code much but anyone is free to ask questions in form of comments right in the code:

**Screen:**

[image]

**Progress Handler:**

public interface ProgressHandler {

```
public void startProgress();

public void updateProgress(String message, int progress);

public void stopProgress();
```

}

**Main View:**

```
public class MainView {
private JComponent view = null;

private ProgressView progressView = null;
private LoadDataView loadDataView = null;

public MainView(){
    progressView = new ProgressView();
    loadDataView = new LoadDataView();
}

public JComponent getView(){
    if (view == null) view = createView();
    return view;
}

private JComponent createView(){
    JPanel result = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );

    result.add( progressView.getView(), BorderLayout.NORTH );
    result.add( loadDataView.getView(), BorderLayout.CENTER );

    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    MainView mainView = new MainView();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add( mainView.getView() );

    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

**Progress View**

```
public class ProgressView {

private static ProgressHandlerImpl progressHandler = new ProgressHandlerImpl(); 

private JComponent view = null;

public static ProgressHandler getProgressHandler(){
    return progressHandler;
}

public JComponent getView(){
    if (view == null) view = createView();
    return view;
}

private JComponent createView(){
    JPanel result = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );        
    result.add( progressHandler.getMessageLabel(), BorderLayout.NORTH );
    result.add( progressHandler.getProgressBar(), BorderLayout.CENTER );
    return result;
}

private static class ProgressHandlerImpl implements ProgressHandler{
    public JProgressBar progressBar = null;
    public JLabel messageLabel = null;

    public ProgressHandlerImpl(){
        progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setVisible(false);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        messageLabel = new JLabel();
        messageLabel.setVisible(false);
    }

    public JProgressBar getProgressBar(){
        return progressBar;
    }

    public JLabel getMessageLabel(){
        return messageLabel;
    }

    @Override
    public void startProgress(){
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable(){ public void run(){
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        progressBar.setVisible(true); } } );            
    }

    @Override
    public void updateProgress(String message, int progress) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable(){  public void run(){
        progressBar.setValue(progress); 

        if (message == null) return;

        if ( !messageLabel.isVisible() ) messageLabel.setVisible(true);

        messageLabel.setText(message);
        } } );  
    }

    @Override
    public void stopProgress(){
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable(){  public void run(){
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        progressBar.setVisible(false); 
        messageLabel.setVisible(false);} } );  
    }       
}
```

}

**Load View**

```
public class LoadDataView {
private JComponent view = null;
private Thread thread = null;

public JComponent getView(){
    if (view == null) view = createView();
    return view;
}

private JComponent createView(){
    JPanel result = new JPanel();

    JButton startProgressButton = new JButton("start");
    startProgressButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { startProgress(); } } );        
    result.add(startProgressButton);

    JButton stopProgressButton = new JButton("stop");
    stopProgressButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { stopProgress(); } } );        
    result.add(stopProgressButton);

    return result;
}

private void startProgress(){
    if (thread != null) throw new IllegalStateException();

    thread = new Thread( new Runnable(){ public void run(){
        ProgressView.getProgressHandler().startProgress();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            ProgressView.getProgressHandler().updateProgress("Loading...", i);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {                   
                ProgressView.getProgressHandler().updateProgress("Loading stopped!", i);
                //do some other logging
                break;
            }
        }

    } } );

    thread.start();
}

private void stopProgress(){
    if (thread == null) return;

    thread.interrupt(); 

    thread = null;
}
```

}

Comment: it wasnt exacly like that
i used 
" public static final javax.swing.JProgressBar p1hp = new javax.swing.JProgressBar(); " instead (because i cant manually modify it, it was ether final or not static)

Comment: So you're recommending that he toss out object-oriented programming principles, that he fix things *backwards* by making them static, that he use static to allow sharing of fields between classes? This is not a good recommendation. **Much** better to show him how to fix the code so statics aren't needed.

Comment: @XaralabosNikolaidhs: for the good of future visitors to this site, please accept either of the other two answers, the ones that don't give recommendations that may mislead newbie future visitors to this site.

Comment: First, having static Progress bar is totally fine, this is in order to be able to start/stop it from anywhere in your code. There is always better way to design it, but is out of this question scope. Second, I said 'as a quick' fix to get going. The answer is exactly what question was asking. The issue was a tricky one and less obvious than the standard 'dont use static' answer. At least give some credit where it is due. Third, it is not always clear cut what is best practice for a given application, and giving an advice that seems like a common sense can actually lead to a wrong direction

Comment: Thanks, I saw that you did. My comment was addressed to @Hovercraft Full Of Eels.

Comment: i understand that "static" and whatsoever is a 'bad' way to fix things but i could not figure a other way with my current knowledge of things. Can any of you like, create it from the beginning with your own ways?
i am curious and wanna see the right way

Comment: I will try to add code to the answer sometimes soon.

Answer (score 2):

Do not put the `JProgressBar` static, instead, add a getter that would allow you to get it in your main. You will face other issue because of your design tho.

```
public JProgressBar getProgressBar()
{
    return p1hp;
}
```

And then in your main :

```
UI ui = new UI();
final JProgressBar progressBar = ui.getProgressBar();
```

To set values in your main use :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            UI ui = new UI();
            ui.setVisible(true);
            ui.getProgressBar().setStringPainted(true);
            ui.getProgressBar().setValue(12);
        }
    });
```

Comment: nope, doesnt display anything by using my 2 lines progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
            progressBar.setValue(12);

Comment: Because you are not in the UI thread. You can fix this by using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` and create a new anonymous `Runnable` inside. I will update to reflect this.

Comment: ok, tnx, this works too. A other guy above game me a different answer which worked too, i will ask my teacher which1 is better :P

Comment: Mine is, using static references for UI components is very bad practice. ;)

Comment: Note: it works even if i remove thoses 2 lines UI ui = new UI();
final JProgressBar progressBar = ui.getProgressBar();  
Before i set my values

Comment: i am still using my progressbar as static, if i remove it, i get the "non-static variable p1hp cannot be referenced from a static context" error, but the problem is solved anyway, which was the nullexception

Answer (score 0):

> I manually maked the progressbar static bacause if not, I would get
>   the error

You can create your class object and then access using that object. This will prevent you from

```
non-static variable p1hp cannot be referenced from a static context
```

But it is not good for here because when you create new object from `UI` new `JFrame` will create.

Wrap using try-catch block. This will handle your exception.

```
try{
    //where null values occur
}catch(NullPointerException e){
  System.out.println("errr");//you dont want add this but it is good to display something.
}
```

**UPDATE:**

From looking at your code I think you are creating GUI's in netbeans. If it is you have to do as following,

**Right click on `JProgressBar` in navigator** or in `JFrame`. Next, goto **custom code** and then tick the **`static`** and change **Access:** to `public. And then you can do any changes.

Or:

In that window add your code for `JProgressBar` in `initialization code`

[image]

Now you donot even need to make it `static`.

Comment: it prints the "errr" fine but i still want to add value to it :/

Comment: Are you use netbeans

Comment: i already have it public on the code i posted

Comment: @XaralabosNikolaidhs Im sorry not the `public`, `static`. then you can add in main as above your code

Comment: i lost u, if u mean removing the static and leaving it just public then i already said what happens, it give me a "non-static variable p1hp cannot be referenced from a static context" error... also i cant modify anything inside the "private void initComponents()", probably a netbeans thing, i dont know

Comment: @XaralabosNikolaidhs You can make it `public` and `static` and edit in souece code but their is a simpler way I added it as a image. try that out

Comment: as i said, i want to modify it through my main. I have some other classes which i use some methods from them to get some numbers, which i want to use on this progressbar. I am not sure if i can use thoses methods on the area u are talking about

Comment: You can create object from that classes inside in it and do whatever you want